# What i want in my code is that my code has to read some locations that are set in numbers out the database

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I add Numbers out the database to my code C# and then show them random on my form? What i want in my code is that my code has to read some locations that are set in numbers out the database and then I have to say that those locations are going to some random point on my form?

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tmLoop.Start();
        string selectSQL;
        selectSQL = "SELECT * from locaties";


        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=patn4lj1;Uid=root;Pwd=root;");
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selectSQL, conn);
        MySqlDataReader reader;

        List<Array> Locaties = new List<Array>();

        try
              {
                 conn.Open();
                 reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                 while (reader.Read())
                     {
                         string data1 = reader.GetString(0);
                         string data2 = reader.GetString(1);
                         string data3 = reader.GetString(2); 
                         string data4 = reader.GetString(3);
                         string data5 = reader.GetString(4);
                         Locaties = 
                         Locaties.Add(data1);
                     }
                     reader.Close();
              }

                  catch (Exception )
                      {
                          MessageBox.Show("niks kunnen vinden uit de database!");
                      }

                  finally
                      {
                        conn.Close();
                      }
 }
```

**Please help me I'm beginner and I dont know what to do!
I thank you very much!!! sry for bad Englisch.

ask me questions if you want something to know thx again!!!

X    Y
30   30
200  350
111  150
22   700
0    300

X and Y are two tables in my database.

**

Comment: Store `x` , `y` in a `List` and loop through the `List` to get the positions, what's your problem with that?

Comment: I dont know how to write the code?

Comment: Please tell what is working and what do you have problems with

Comment: I can not store X and Y in to my Code I dont know how to do that?

Comment: What are the fields in `locaties`?

Comment: You read from a table called `locaties`  right? Which fields has it? Look in `MySQL Workbench`

Comment: X Y 30 30 200 350 111 150 22 700 0 300

Comment: X = 30 30 200 350 111           Y= 150 22 700 0 300

Answer (score 0):

You can store the coordinates in a `List` to use them later on. Here's an example:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    tmLoop.Start();
    string selectSQL;
    selectSQL = "SELECT * from locaties";       

    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=patn4lj1;Uid=root;Pwd=root;");
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selectSQL, conn);
    MySqlDataReader reader;

    List<Point> Locaties = new List<Point>();

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int xPos = reader.GetInt32(0);
            int yPos = reader.GetInt32(1);
            Locaties.Add(new Point(xPos,yPos));
        }
        reader.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("niks kunnen vinden uit de database!");
    }

    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

 }
```